# High charts displays data only if we press F12 (developer tool) in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have used high chart to display column bar and pie chart. I don't know why this problem is occurring.

The problem is that the chart should be displayed on load time of jsp file, but only data is showing on load time; when we press f12 then it renders the charts.

I don't know why.

If anyone faced this problem before.

Comment: Please show us the code you use.

Comment: It means that redraw is called, so it looks like problem with draw chart, during initialise chart. Anyway without any live demo it is difficult to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any console.log()'s?

Take them out if you do.