# Javascript chart only appears when toggling 'developer tools' (F12) in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, developer-tools, canvasjs

Similar to [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452854/), only with a different charting library ([CanvasJS](http://canvasjs.com/)), and with my code included.

Chart appears only after 'developer tools' has been **toggled** (ie. switch from on-off OR off-on).

Code I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="generator" content=
"HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.canvasjs.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var dataPoints = [];
(function () {
        $.getJSON('boop.little.json',
                function(thedata) {
                        $.each(thedata, function(i, v) {
                                dataPoints.push({ x: new Date(v.Datetime), y: parseFloat(v.Value) });
                        });
                }
        )
})();

$(function () {
        var options = {
                data: [{
                        type: "splineArea", //change it to column, spline, line, pie, etc
                        dataPoints: dataPoints
                        }
                ]
        };

        $("#chartContainer").CanvasJSChart(options);
});
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
<div id="chartContainer2" style="width:100%; height:300px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON source:

```
[
    {
        "Datetime": "01/01/2012 00:00:01",
        "Value": "0.48"
    },
    {
        "Datetime": "01/01/2012 00:10:01",
        "Value": "0.50"
    },
    {
        "Datetime": "01/01/2012 00:20:01",
        "Value": "0.48"
    },
    {
        "Datetime": "01/01/2012 00:30:01",
        "Value": "0.49"
    },
    {
        "Datetime": "01/01/2012 00:40:01",
        "Value": "0.50"
    },
    {
        "Datetime": "01/01/2012 00:50:01",
        "Value": "0.47"
    },
    {
        "Datetime": "01/01/2012 01:00:01",
        "Value": "1.23"
    },
    {
        "Datetime": "01/01/2012 01:10:01",
        "Value": "2.09"
    },
    {
        "Datetime": "01/01/2012 01:20:01",
        "Value": "2.08"
    },
    {
        "Datetime": "01/01/2012 01:30:01",
        "Value": "2.64"
    },
    {
        "Datetime": "01/01/2012 01:40:01",
        "Value": "2.91"
    },
    {
        "Datetime": "01/01/2012 01:50:01",
        "Value": "0.49"
    },
    {
        "Datetime": "01/01/2012 02:00:01",
        "Value": "0.50"
    },
    {
        "Datetime": "01/01/2012 02:10:01",
        "Value": "0.49"
    },
    {
        "Datetime": "01/01/2012 02:20:01",
        "Value": "0.53"
    },
    {
        "Datetime": "01/01/2012 02:30:01",
        "Value": "0.51"
    }
]
```

Interestingly (and the reason it appears), removing the line:

```
<div id="chartContainer2" style="width:100%; height:300px;"></div>
```

Stops the chart rendering at all! (even with toggling developer tools).
Something fishy going on here, can anyone suggest some further debugging?

Cheers,

-Phil

PS. FYI: Nothing displayed in IE9, regardless of F12 toggle (expected IE behaviour?).

Comment: Put debugger inside $.each and verify if the response is in required format. (debugger works in chrome)

Comment: Not sure I follow... To reiterate: the chart does appear (correctly) when toggling the developer tools function. I think it's fair to assume the data format is correct if it's charting correctly.

Comment: At first try to set the width to a specific width, like 500px - it could be the canvas attempts to render before the DOM / canvas is loaded - therefor being 0 width.
And I would try to use the function where the canvas gets drawn on doc.ready > you know all elements are present.

Comment: Nice idea - after setting a fixed (smaller) pixel dimension, the chart doesnt render at all... Though interestingly, it looks as if running developer tools has the effect of introducing a scrollbar (therefore resizing) the chart! Might be on to something here... I'll keep playing.

Comment: Yeah, the chart is rendered upon **re**size of the div!